# Forwarding all trafic with ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, tunneling, ip-forwarding

I have two ubuntu server, one server from Iran and other from England

On the England server run V2ray vpn and i should have some tunnel from iran server to foreign country for best quality of speed and something like china great firewall to pass throw hard filtering. I see some people in iran to config servers with ipv6 and get the best result, now i do something but i have problem in tunneling.
i setup hurricane electric tunnel broker on the both servers to have ipv6 enabling

now i want to create tunnel between servers to forward all traffic from Iran server to England server...

Can you help me how should i do this?